# What defines the 'name' of a score i.e. gamma, kappa etc

Tags: statistics, naming-conventions

I was just wondering if there is a process or set of properties that exist to name a score, such as, Cohen’s ***Kappa***, Fleiss’ ***Kappa***, Krippendorff’s ***Alpha***, or if it is just at the creators choice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One would have to be pretty vain to name such a thing after oneself: "Kimchilover's Qoph", forsooth.  Maybe the name accretes, like "Student's T" or "Euler's gamma".

Comment: Sorry, I realise I might have made it a bit unclear. I meant the naming conventions for which greek (or arabic in your example) letter to choose

Comment: I think the original poster meant to ask, why do people name things with Greek letters instead of our usual Roman letters? Not clear is *what people* or *what kinds of things*. Let me guess, from ignorance, that the poster is interested in psychology or one of its offshoots, and that psychologists and psychometricians have a penchant to name things after Greek letters. Maybe because the name of their subject begins with a Greek letter?